# How do I cancel the current build in space engineers

Tags: space-engineers

I'm new to Space Engineers so apologies if this is a numpty question, but I've managed to enter a build mode for a part, and it's ghosting in front of me all the time as I move around, as shown below.

[image: Space Engineers Ghosted Build]

I've no intention or desire to build this object right now, so I'd like to stop it from showing in front of me all the time so I can get on with what I'm trying to do.

Can anyone suggest what I need to do to make it disappear?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's a glitch, which I've encountered plenty. What you want to do is put a part (any part) in your quickbar, switch to it, then switch to anything else (tools, empty hand, etc.) So far as I can tell, the game just kinda gets 'stuck' sometimes.

Comment: I'm glad it's a bug, as I was thinking it wasn't very intuitive to stop. Workaround does the trick though. Thanks.

Comment: It seems to have been introduced in the latest patch, and I suspect it'll be removed in the next one. Lately they've been updating just about once a week, and the last one was May 1, so quite possibly some time this week.

Comment: It was as you predicted, fixed in the next update (01.029)